# How to stop executing rest of setup script in Vue 3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have child page with code like that

```
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
const isSomething = inject('isSomething')

if (!isSomething.value) {
  router.replace('/somepage')
}

// rest of setup script with a lot of code
// like api data fetch
</script>
```

And it works, so it will redirect if condition is false. Problem is - Vue still executes rest of script setup, for example fetching all API data event that it's not needed.

Is there a way to just "stop" script setup?

I cannot use middleware for that because my condition is based on ref variable provided from parent page. If I try to inject that in router hooks level - it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's done as in any other place in JavaScript:

```
if (!isSomething.value) {
  router.replace('/somepage')
} else {
  // rest of setup script with a lot of code
}
```

That there's "a lot of code" suggests that view component can be refactored to contain only the code that is essential for a route, the rest of the content can be extracted to nested component.

Comment: it's not allowed in script setup - everything in that else will be not available for the page (template)

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: in vue script setup every const will be exported to component, but only if it is on root level. So if I put some data, for example api fetch method with response in that else {} or any loop etc, it will be not available later.

Comment: Proceed from this and define all template vars with `let` outside `if` block. The problem is that the template still may be rendered at least once even if you do router.replace, this depends on router lifecycle and isn't documented. As noted in the answer, you won't have this problem if you keep page contents in a separate component. If this is still a problem, consider explaining your case further. Probably you could use global store instead of inject to get rid of the dependence on setup, or could refactor components in some way that would prevent this problem.